# Convert json format to another json format by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm trying to implement a questionnaire with angularjs,So I have the following response array ,I need to convert this object array to json format like the following output, So How can I convert object array to json format?

```
 var response=[{"questiongroup":1,"question":1,"response":"response1"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":2,"response":"response2"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":3,"response":"response3"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":4,"response":"response4"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":5,"response":"response5"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":6,"response":"response6"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":7,"response":"response7"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":8,"response":"response8"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":9,"response":"response9"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":10,"response":"response10"}];
```

desired output

```
   {"questiongroups": [
                       {
                         "questiongroup": 1,
                         "question": [
                           {
                             "question": 1,
                             "response":"response1"
                           },
                           {
                             "question": 2,
                             "response":"response2"
                            },
                            {
                             "question": 3,
                             "response":"response3"
                             },
                            {
                             "question": 4,
                             "response":"response4"
                              },
                             {
                              "question": 5,
                              "response":"response5"
                             }]
                         },
                         {
                             "questiongroup": 2,
                             "question": [
                               {
                                 "question": 6,
                                 "response":"response6"
                               },
                               {
                                 "question": 7,
                                 "response":"response7"
                                },
                                {
                                 "question": 8,
                                 "response":"response8"
                                 },
                                {
                                 "question": 9,
                                 "response":"response9"
                                  },
                                 {
                                  "question": 10,
                                  "response":"response10"
                                 }]
                             }
                         ]
                    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty in marking this as a duplicate -- it appears that you're not asking how to convert this object to JSON, you're asking how to rearrange the data into a different structure.

Comment: yes, It differ I need to change the format.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Data mutation like this is very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution that came to me.

Reduces the response to a object with the questiongroup being the ids of the arrays. Then, to return as you want, mapped the keys to generate the array and created the object with the questiongroups value.

```js
var response=[{"questiongroup":1,"question":1,"response":"response1"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":2,"response":"response2"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":3,"response":"response3"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":4,"response":"response4"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":5,"response":"response5"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":6,"response":"response6"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":7,"response":"response7"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":8,"response":"response8"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":9,"response":"response9"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":10,"response":"response10"}];

var questiongroups = response.reduce(function(groups, question){
  var group = groups[question.questiongroup] || [];
  group.push({
    question: question.question,
    response: question.response
  });

  groups[question.questiongroup] = group;
  
  return groups;
}, {});

questiongroups = Object.keys(questiongroups).map(function (key) {return {questiongroup: key, question: questiongroups[key]}});

var object = {
  questiongroups: questiongroups
};

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thanks tpsilva that's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response=[{"questiongroup":1,"question":1,"response":"response1"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":2,"response":"response2"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":3,"response":"response3"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":4,"response":"response4"},
                     {"questiongroup":1,"question":5,"response":"response5"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":6,"response":"response6"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":7,"response":"response7"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":8,"response":"response8"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":9,"response":"response9"},
                     {"questiongroup":2,"question":10,"response":"response10"}];

var result = {
 "questiongroups": [],
}

var group = {
 "questiongroup": 1,
  "question": []
}

for (var i in response) {

 if (response[i].questiongroup != group.questiongroup) {
   result.questiongroups.push(group);
    group = {
    "questiongroup" : response[i].questiongroup,
   "question": []
    };
  }
  
  var entry = {
    "question" : {
      "question" : response[i].question,
      "response" : response[i].response
    }
  }
  
  group.question.push(entry);
}

result.questiongroups.push(group);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for your effort